# Does committing changes on a branch discard them from other branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

Consider the following scenario:

1. Make a clean clone of a repo
2. Change some files
3. Stage the changes
4. Create a new branch
5. Commit the changes to the new branch
6. Delete the branch

Are the changes lost forever?

Comment: You never checked out a new commit or branch so even though the “old branch” is gone, the commit it pointed to is actually in you’re current branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question you used as title:

> Does committing changes on a branch discard them from other branches?

Nothing gets deleted from other branches when you commit to a branch. In your scenario, you never added the changes to your main branch. They were in your working tree (when you wrote those changes), then you updated the index to match your working tree (when you staged those changes), but you never added the changes to the main branch since you never committed to that branch. So it's not that they got deleted from that branch, it's that they were never added to it.

What may give you the impression that your changes got deleted is that, when you switched to a new branch to commit your changes there, then switched back to your main branch, the working tree got updated to match what is on the branch and you don't see the changes anymore.

As for whether the changes are lost forever, @Paolo and @matt already answered:

The changes are not lost until the next garbage collection (gc) which, by defaults, runs every 30 days. They will indeed get lost when the commit pointing to that snapshot gets cleaned by the next gc since it is not on any branch.

Until then, you can recover your changes, for instance, by:

1. Checking out the commit containing the changes (you deleted the branch, which is only a pointer, but the commit is still there). This will put you in a detached HEAD state since HEAD will not be pointing to a branch, as it usually do, but directly to a commit:

```sh
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

This only works if you do it right after deleting your branch. If you have moved HEAD around, you will need to run `git reflog` to look for the commit hash and use `git checkout <hash>` instead.

2. Creating a new branch from that commit and checking it out (you will not be in a detached HEAD state anymore since HEAD will now be pointing to that new branch):

```sh
git checkout -b newbranch
```

From there on, you can merge your new branch back into your main branch or do whatever you want with it. The commit you cared about is now on a branch, so it will not get deleted by the next gc.

Answer (score 2):

> Are the changes lost forever?

No. You can recover the deleted commit with:

```
$ git reflog
```

Answer (score 0):

> Are the changes lost forever?

Not immediately. But if no reference (such as a tag or branch name) points to a commit or to one of its descendants, then yes, it will eventually be cleaned up and lost.